# in the ViewController.m, what's the difference between self.username with _username

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, object-code

```
@synthesize username = _username;
//Method1
    - (void) viewDidLoad
{
self.username = @"admin";
}

//Method2
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   _username = @"admin"
}
```

Both are worked, and what's the difference? 
can I use _username at all? when I use self.username,it will go @synthesize username; 
Is self.username a method？
_username just a variable?
I write the _username in several methods. It also can worked in the View.
self.username is faster than _username or not?

Comment: Check http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocproperties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self.username` will call the setter of the `username` that's why the breakpoint jumps to the `synthesize` statement.

When you a _variable, then the property can be accessed using the _variable.
And in your case:

`self.username` stores the value to ivar `_username` and `_username = @"admin";` is also stores the value to `_username` ivar. Means both saves to same ivar `_username`.

> Listing 4-2  Using @synthesize
>   You can use the form property=ivar to indicate that a particular
>   instance variable should be used for the property, for example:
>
> @synthesize firstName, lastName, age=yearsOld;
>
> This specifies that the accessor methods for firstName, lastName, and
>   age should be synthesized and that the property age is represented by
>   the instance variable yearsOld. Other aspects of the synthesized
>   methods are determined by the optional attributes

Please refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocproperties.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go through the [apple documentation - Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocproperties.html). `self.username` is equivalent to the getter and setter methods in other languages. Just a few things about this. Before ARC, it used to help in ensuring following the memory management part as well(Handling retain, release, copy of params). `_username` is mostly used in methods such as `init` when it is not recommended to use `self.param` in `init` and `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between self.username with _username.

self.username uses accessors (setter and getters). They call the method and in the method the ivar is accessed.

_username uses the ivar directly. NO method call, so this may save a bit of overhead.

self.username makes your class KVO compliant, while _username bypasses it.

Comment: Tank you, I haven't seen KVO and KVC , I will Google it. It's a little different Java.

Comment: In one line... when one object changes the other object gets notified.

Comment: And if you find anything good please do upvote and accept.